# JavaScript - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm building some ChatApp and i got JavaScript SyntaxError, I don't see anything wrong, so could you help me,
Terminal output: **SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
←[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)←[39m**
here is the code:

sever.js:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()
var http = require('http').Server(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(http)
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

var dbUrl = 'mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@cluster0.yihif.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

var Message = mongoose.model('Message', {

    name : String,
    message: String
})



app.get('/messages', (req,res)=>{
    Message.find({}, (err,messages) =>{
        res.send(messages)
    })

})
app.post('/messages', (req, res)=> {
    var message = new Message(req.body)

    message.save((err) => {
        if (err)
            sendStatus(500)
        message.save((err) => {


            io.emit('message', req.body)
            res.sendStatus(200)
        })
    })


    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log("user connected")
    })

    mongoose.connect(dbUrl, (err) => {

        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB')
    })

    var server = http.listen(3010, () => {

        console.log("SERVER WORKS AT PORT", server.address().port, "!!!!")
    })
```

ps I got error in my IDE that says missing } on the last line, but that doesn't work

Comment: You are missing a } and a )

Comment: Oh, thanks, I literally didn't see that lol

Comment: Why am I losing reputation with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly braces on line 27 is not closed.